# Why are there strange postal addresses in my Chrome auto-fill settings?

Tags: google-chrome, security, auto-form-fill

I opened the Settings page on Chrome browser today to make some password setting changes and accidentally clicked the `Manage Auto-fill settings` directly above the password settings button.

I was greeted with a window which showed me, apparently, all saved auto-fill settings. In this list there are 3 addresses which I do not recognise in the slightest - they are for areas which I have no reason to visit (i.e no family etc there).

None of these unrecognised addresses have a name associated with them.

Am I missing something or is this very unusual?

EDIT: Just to clarify I'm talking postal addresses, not email addresses

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you're connected to your google account, these adresses *could* come from some other source e.g. your chrome on your Android (Don't know about apple) or just any other browser where you might have logged in and forgot to logout, as an example grab some mail from gmail on some computer in a rush and logging into chrome by accident.
Click [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) to open up a page where you can see all your active google logins.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, firstly I have been using this option for a quite a long time and it helps me to autofill my forms when I am applying for something.

[image]

Most probably the addresses you are seeing were entered by someone else (your friend) who might have used your laptop.

You can simply delete those address.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have no connection with the areas saved in there, I don't have any friends / family who live / have lived there. Its very odd and slightly worrying!

Comment: @JonnyWright - just noticed the same thing in my Chrome auto-fill. 1 correct and valid address, and 2 weird and totally unrelated addresses. Of which, one at least is in the same country as me - but the other is on the other side of the world. No chance whatsoever that someone else entered them while logged in as me on my laptop/phone.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my listings include addresses I have entered to make payments online through my bank. The addresses are ones I entered into bank forms to set up a payment account.